# Глобально отследить нажатие кнопок мыши c#

Tags: c#

В программе нужно отловить нажатие кнопки мыши, чтобы сделать действие.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
 
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (isLButtonDown())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Кнопка нажата!");
            }
}
 
bool isLButtonDown()
{
            Int16 state = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton);
            return (state & 0x8000) != 0;
}
```

Что удалось найти, но срабатывает через раз.

Comment: Что-то вроде события при потере фокуса элемента, но в приложение может быть только один элемент принимающий фокус, или щелчок на элементе не принимающий фокус.

Comment: При нажатии на что? На что-то конкретное, или на любой контрол?

Comment: Вы в своём приложении хотите ловить события мыши или в чужом? Какого типа приложение?

Comment: Да в своем приложении, ловить клик.

Comment: Цель: в textbox ввожу текст, если нажимаю мышью не на него, textbox превращается в label

Comment: Как вариант у всех контролов на форме проверять клик

Comment: [Leave](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=net-5.0), [LostFocus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=net-5.0). В секции Remarks смотрите порядок событий

Comment: Leave точно не то, LostFocus сработает если клик на контрол который принимает фокус, например клик на Panel ничего не даст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Int32 vKey);

...
private void TextBoxTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((GetAsyncKeyState(1) != 0) || (GetAsyncKeyState(2) != 0) || (GetAsyncKeyState(4) != 0))
        {
            if (!Tb.ClientRectangle.Contains(Tb.PointToClient(MousePosition))) FromTextBoxToLabel(Tb.Text);
        }
    }
```

На таймер вешаем обработку если нажата ЛКМ (1) или ПКМ (2) или средняя (4), то что-то происходит нужное нам. Работает.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый объект на форме, кроме вашего TextBox, и саму форму кликнуть ЛКМ. Затем в окне Properties выберете вкладку Events со значком молния, там вы найдете события, связанные с мышью, кликните 2 раза и создастся обработчик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне надо наоборот, ловить клик вне элемента, выше написал как.

Comment: Исправил ответ под ваше уточнение.

Comment: Да спасибо, может есть другой способ, типо глобальный хук.

Comment: Да круто, я понял, перебрать все контролы которые есть и будущие и у вех на клик сделать обработчик, да это сработает.